# Android - How I can listen edge effect on ListView (like pull to refresh) ?

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I want to use pure-Android patterns to build my UI. Therefore, i prefer to use Edge Effect instead Pull-to-Refresh (seems near of IOS UI patterns).

I already search/read this answer at Android docs, but not foud anything like Java interface to implement or public method at ScrollView that returns EdgeEffect instance for me.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html